# Converting ruby array into a hash with symbols

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, hash, symbols

Im still pretty new to programming, and i am trying to convert an array of strings into a hash with symbols. The formatting of the strings are giving me grief:

```
foobar = ["ABC: OPEN", "123: OPEN", "FOO: CLOSED", "BAR: CLOSED", "XYZ: OPEN", "LMO: CLOSED"]
```

I am trying to get this "name: status" format to transfer to a hash where the key can be a symbol:

```
foobar_hash = {"ABC" => :OPEN, "123" => :OPEN, "FOO" => :CLOSED, "BAR" => :CLOSED, "XYZ" => :CLOSED, "LMO" => :CLOSED}
```

What would be the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: This would actually be a decent code golf question.

Comment: yes. Sorry i have edited it appropriately

Comment: does `:OPEN` need to be a string or a symbol as you've indicated?

Comment: yes i am trying to get symbols

Comment: Why the rush in selecting an answer?

Comment: `eval '{'+foobar.map { |s| f,l = s.split(/:\s+/); "\"#{f}\"=>:#{l}" }.join(',')+'}'` works, but I wouldn't advise it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
[4] pry(main)> foobar = ["ABC: OPEN", "123: OPEN", "FOO: CLOSED", "BAR: CLOSED", "XYZ: OPEN", "LMO: CLOSED"]

=> ["ABC: OPEN", "123: OPEN", "FOO: CLOSED", "BAR: CLOSED", "XYZ: OPEN", "LMO: CLOSED"]
[5] pry(main)> foobar.map { |i| i.split(": ") }.to_h
=> {"ABC"=>"OPEN",
 "123"=>"OPEN",
 "FOO"=>"CLOSED",
 "BAR"=>"CLOSED",
 "XYZ"=>"OPEN",
 "LMO"=>"CLOSED"}
```

If you need the `colon` in front of the `value` you can do something like this too:

```
[14] pry(main)> foobar.map { |i| i.gsub(": ", " :") }.map { |j| j.split(" ") }.to_h
=> {"ABC"=>":OPEN",
 "123"=>":OPEN",
 "FOO"=>":CLOSED",
 "BAR"=>":CLOSED",
 "XYZ"=>":OPEN",
 "LMO"=>":CLOSED"}
```

One more iteration if you need the values to be symbols, you could do this:

```
[35] pry(main)> foobar.map { |i| i.split(": ") }.each_with_object({}) do |array, hash|
[35] pry(main)*   hash[array.first] = array.last.to_sym
[35] pry(main)* end

=> {"ABC"=>:OPEN, "123"=>:OPEN, "FOO"=>:CLOSED, "BAR"=>:CLOSED, "XYZ"=>:OPEN, "LMO"=>:CLOSED}
```

Comment: this worked great. Needed to update from 2.0.0 to 2.1.5 for .to_h. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Something like this?

```
arr = [
  "ABC: OPEN",
  "123: OPEN",
  "FOO: CLOSED",
  "BAR: CLOSED",
  "XYZ: OPEN",
  "LMO: CLOSED"
]
```

---

```
Hash[arr.map { |x| x.split ": " }]

=> {"ABC"=>"OPEN",
"123"=>"OPEN",
"FOO"=>"CLOSED",
"BAR"=>"CLOSED",
"XYZ"=>"OPEN",
"LMO"=>"CLOSED"}
```

If you want symbol key/values: `Hash[arr.map { |x| x.split(": ").map(&:to_sym) }]`

Comment: The OP could not been more clear that values are to be symbols, so why have more than what's in your last sentence? (+1 fot that.)

Comment: @CarySwoveland I am a _fan_ of `each_with_object`... :-)

Comment: @Arup, I've noticed and prefer it's use here.

Answer (score 1):

One more way :-

```
arr = [
  "ABC: OPEN",
  "123: OPEN",
  "FOO: CLOSED",
  "BAR: CLOSED",
  "XYZ: OPEN",
  "LMO: CLOSED"
]

arr.each_with_object({}) do |string, hash| 
  key, val = string.scan(/\w+/)
  hash[key] = val.to_sym
end

# => {"ABC"=>:OPEN,
#     "123"=>:OPEN,
#     "FOO"=>:CLOSED,
#     "BAR"=>:CLOSED,
#     "XYZ"=>:OPEN,
#     "LMO"=>:CLOSED}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work :

```
foobar_hash = {}
foobar.each { |s| foobar_hash[s.split(":")[0].strip] = s.split(":")[1].strip.to_sym }
```

Comment: Would you remove your `do` ? :-)

Comment: added '.strip' to remove any trailing white spaces.

Answer (score 0):

```
foobar = ["ABC: OPEN", "123: OPEN", "FOO: CLOSED", "BAR: CLOSED", "XYZ: OPEN", "LMO: CLOSED"]
foo_hash = Hash.new
foobar.each { |str| k,v = str.split(': '); foo_hash[k] = v.to_sym }
```

foo_hash gives you

```
=> {"ABC"=>:OPEN, "123"=>:OPEN, "FOO"=>:CLOSED, "BAR"=>:CLOSED, "XYZ"=>:OPEN, "LMO"=>:CLOSED}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this

```
keys = "foobar".map{|s|s.split(':')}.map(&:first)
values = "foobar".map{|s|s.split(':')}.map(&:last)

Hash[keys.zip(values)]
```